# How do grandfather clocks keep going?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, time

How do [grandfather clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longcase_clock) keep going? The pendulum is what makes the clock go. However, the pendulum will slow down due to friction. What energy source keeps the pendulum from eventually stopping?

Comment: have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_clock#Mechanism

Comment: @Ovi I think you should reconsider which answer is correct.

Comment: [They don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Grandfather%27s_Clock#Lyrics)

Comment: @ThomasW ouch...

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The premise of your question is incorrect:  in fact, the pendulum is what keeps the clock **from** running!  And the clock keeps the pendulum running!

A clock is essentially a motor:  a device that uses energy from some source to drive the hands of the clock around and around.  The source of the energy varies;  it could be a tightly wound spring, or a weight dropping down after being raised to some height.  The energy is dissipated in the friction in the various gears that are used to reduce the speed of the motor for the different hands.  The speed of this motor would depend only on the friction in the various gears...

The role of the pendulum is critical.  In part of its motion back and forth, it **stops** the gear train from moving.  As the pendulum moves further in its swing, it releases a tooth of the gear, which rotates a little until another part of the pendulum catches another tooth.  So each swing of the pendulum allows the clock "motor" to rotate only a fixed number of teeth (usually one tooth exactly)

Here's a simple example of an **escapement**:
[image]

The next trick is to have the teeth of the gear give a little push to the pendulum as each tooth is released.  This compensates for the friction in the pendulum which would otherwise stop the pendulum in a few hours.  So the energy source in the clock is keeping the pendulum swinging, as the pendulum regulates the rotation of the gear...

Comment: There is a nice video of this at https://youtu.be/z_7rE8afFfo?t=6s

Answer (score 7):

They do stop without intervention. Grandfather clocks have to be reset. They are designed so that you can wind them back up.

[image]

Most have holes/keys around here where they can be winded back up.

Most are made to be able to go about a week without winding.

> "Traditionally, longcase clocks were made with two types of movement:
>   eight-day and one-day (30-hour) movements. A clock with an eight-day
>   movement required winding only once a week, while generally less
>   expensive 30-hour clocks had to be wound every day. Eight-day clocks
>   are often driven by two weights – one driving the pendulum and the
>   other the striking mechanism, which usually consisted of a bell or
>   chimes. Such movements usually have two keyholes on either side of the
>   dial to wind each one (as can be seen in the Thomas Ross clock above).
>   By contrast, 30-hour clocks often had a single weight to drive both
>   the timekeeping and striking mechanisms. Some 30-hour clocks were made
>   with false keyholes, for customers who wished that guests to their
>   home would think that the household was able to afford the more
>   expensive eight-day clock. All modern striking longcase clocks have
>   eight-day movements. Most longcase clocks are cable-driven, meaning
>   that the weights are suspended by cables. If the cable was attached
>   directly to the weight, the load would cause rotation and untwist the
>   cable strands, so the cable wraps around a pulley mounted to the top
>   of each weight. The mechanical advantage of this arrangement also
>   doubles the running time allowed by a given weight drop."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'd say a poorly developed answer suits a poorly researched question.  If you follow the link in OP's question, the second paragraph leads to two Wikipedia pages for an anchor escapement and verge escapement.  And the page itself explains how the clock works.  So OP didn't do any work of his own; OP just found the Wikipedia page and wanted someone else to give the answer.

Comment: @Ryan I agree that it's a poorly researched question; however, I don't see how adding poorly researched answers enhances the site. Also, the link to Wikipedia was added by somebody else so it's unfair to ding the asker for that.

Comment: Regardless of whether the OP "deserves" to get an incorrect (at best, misleading) answer, this question is on the Hot Network Questions bar and this answer does a disservice to the 1.5k+ people seeing it. The OP explicitly mentions friction and this is not what makes a clock stop when it (eventually) does so. User58220's [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/187421) is the correct explanation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the accepted answer checkmark means very little. Ryan is on spot that it is a sign of the quality of the Question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty the community can vote down the question for its lack of accuracy, and eventually even remove it.

Comment: @Mindwin I may be wrong but I don't think accepted answers can be deleted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed it is so. I stand corrected. We are only left with downvotes as a weapon. Last, the green checkmark means very little to the keen eye these days.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I did not expect such a poorly researched question to get so much attention, so for that I apologize. However, the very link he cited gave the answer.

Comment: There was no link in the original question. Somebody edited it to include the link.

Comment: And thanks for the edit. That's a definite improvement.

Comment: This answer needs a few more upvotes just so @DJohnM  can get the "contrarian" badge...

Answer (score 0):

They do keep on going with regular rewinding of the driving **spring**, rising of the driving **weight** or replacement of the **battery**. What were you expecting!?